# How to hide output password with sharp in ruby?

Tags: ruby, passwords, puts

I want to puts sharp's instead of password in ruby code

```
puts "        found password: #{pass.tr('?','#')}"
```

I need as many sharp '#' characters output as characters in a password.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.tr` is intended to swap specific characters, you cannot do a wild-card match. Even if you extended it to cover many characters, there is a risk that you miss or forget a special character that is allowed in passwords on your system.

A simple variant of what you have is to use `.gsub` instead:

```
pass.gsub(/./,'#')
```

This uses regular expressions to find groups of characters to swap. The simple Regexp `/./` matches *any* single character. The [Ruby core documentation on regular expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) includes a brief introduction, in case you have not used them much before.